# Hebrew UI in emulator

Tags: android, emulation, hebrew

I am trying to test an app that contains Hebrew text. However, I cannot change the android OS to display the UI in hebrew. I don't see Hebrew as one of the language choices in the Language and Input settings.

I tried using `persist.sys.language=iw` and `persist.sys.country=IL`, which shows me Hebrew (Israel) in Hebrew text in the Language setting. But, the rest of the UI is in English and my app is in English as well.

I know that Hebrew shows up as a language choice in my friend's Samsung Android phone.

I am using 4.0 with API level 14 for the emulator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, support for various locales is dependent on the vendor.
Vendors could choose to remove certain locales for whatever reason. Did your friend get the phone from the same vendor/carrier as you did.

If all else fails, there are instructions for rooted phones [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/how-to-install-hebrew-on-a-samsung-galaxy-s-vibrant) and apps on the [Android Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=hebrew&c=apps&price=1&sort=0) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Android support huge variety of locales but it never means that you'll find all language support in all the devices.

In case you want any specific language support in your application you have to package the appropriate fonts for the same in your application.

**Remember Android supports Open Type Fonts only.**

In case you need to install specific font in your phone/ emulator then you need to either buy a device with that font support / root the device or build your own emulator with your specified fonts.

Comment: I can see the hebrew in the phone's /system/fonts folder and it works since I can see some settings in hebrew text when I start the emulator with persist.sys.language=iw  and persist.sys.country=IL. However, most OS UI strings are in English. Is that normal?